# Why is .htaccess mod rewrite rule not activating?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following two rules in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^vacancies/test-feed/vacancies/status?user=(.*)$ vacancies/test-feed.php?mode=status&email=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^vacancies/test-feed/vacancies/(.*)$ vacancies/test-feed.php?mode=vacancy-info&job_id=$1 [L,NC]
```

I am accessing the url:

`/vacancies/test-feed/vacancies/status?user=test@email.com`

and I want that to activate the top rule, but it is actually activating the second and passing `status?user=test@email.com` as `$1`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you done `RewriteEngine On` before the rules

Comment: Have you restarted your apache server?

Comment: You don't need to restart for .htaccess but worth a shot.

Comment: @Minion there is no need to restart the server for changes in `.htaccess`

Comment: I have added RewriteEngine On and other similar rules are working fine. Could it be something to do with the query string in the pattern being matched?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apache administration and as such better fits to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Try adding 
    RewriteLog "/path/to/rewritelog"
    RewriteLogLevel 7
Then seeing which rule is getting hit

Comment: I'm a developer and am using this in an application build

Comment: @TLama mark all of the other .htaccess questions as off topic too then. This could be a regex problem!

Comment: Try escaping the ? so change it to \? (in the regex)

Comment: `RewriteRule` does not handle the query string. Check [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule). You need to prepend the `RewriteRule` with a `RewriteCond` directive that checks the query string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace the first rule with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} user=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^vacancies/test-feed/vacancies/status$ vacancies/test-feed.php?mode=status&email=%1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Nearly. Dangerous to use `(.*)` as the match, this would grab _everything_ after `user=` and therefore consume the rest of the query string if it was present. Better to use `([^&]+)`.